# How to set three Expandable ListView in only one xml in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set three Expandable ListView in Single layout. I tried for this but none of them get scrolled. How to set this? If you have any ideas for this please help me.

Here is my xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_assign_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_assign_save_ok"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_assign_top"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_assign_scrolling"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_assign_my_exercise"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="#2492D6"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="My Execise"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_assign_my_exercise"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_assign_my_exercise"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_assign_my_library"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lv_assign_my_exercise"
            android:background="#2492D6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Library"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_assign_my_library"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_assign_my_library"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
        </ExpandableListView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_assign_my_patient"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lv_assign_my_library"
            android:background="#2492D6"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_assign_my_patient"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_assign_my_patient"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
        </ExpandableListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: @AndroidDeveloper ya this is my current xml.

Comment: Unrelated: you might consider using a LinearLayout instead of a RelativeLayout for the things inside the scroll view, so you won't have to position all the things